# Calling memory and manipulating it in assembly, Intel 8086

Tags: assembly, memory, x86-16, emu8086

I'm trying to run some simple assembly code on simulated Intel 8086 processor. I've come to the source of the problem which was causing my code to not run properly. To be clear the code I was trying to run is provided to me by a book, not my own creation.
The variable br is not put in al register for some reason. If you could help putting that memory location in that register that would be great!

```
    data SEGMENT
     br db 5
     k  db ? 
    data ENDS  
    mov al, br
```

[Here's the debugging window this A0 part is a bit unclear to me, why does it happen?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sSnTi.png)

Comment: Also make sure your `DS` is set up to point at `data`.

Comment: @fuz: emu8086 is MASM-like; `mov al, br` should be a load.

Comment: @PeterCordes Thanks.  I have trouble keeping the finer points of how those obscure assembler's syntaxes work apart.

Comment: @fuz: I don't remember finer points if there are any between emu8086 vs. TASM vs. MASM; I have zero interest in ever making a 16-bit DOS `.exe` myself.  But I do remember that all of the 16-bit assemblers that people ask about on SO are some flavour of MASM syntax (other than NASM / YASM of course), and that bare symbol = memory operand is one of the major diffs for MASM-like syntax.  Until NASM invented better syntax, MASM-like Intel syntax was all we had.  Maybe with varying levels of forcing you to use "variables" with a magic operand-size implication, instead of just plain labels for data.

Comment: @PeterCordes 'mov al, br' should be a load. This does mean that the code should essentially be ok?

Comment: Yes, if the DS register is set to the base of the segment it's in.

Comment: If it's not working, use the debugger built-in to emu8086 to single-step the code and look at register values.

Comment: @PeterCordes yeah DS is set to the base address of the memory segment. It loads the number in memory without any problem but it simply refuses to load it in AL register. He does load something in A register though. It sets A0 in AH and leaves al empty or is it all A000 as it was in AX register?

Comment: @PeterCordes I updated the post with a picture of the debugger with all the values from all registers that may help maybe

Comment: `br` seems to be at `7100h` but you are loading from `7000h`.